# c# fillrectangle MVS 2012

Tags: c#

I am beginner in c# programming and want to draw a rectangle in a windowsformapplication.
I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and got this example code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void FillRectangleRectangle(PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        // Create solid brush.
        SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);

        // Create rectangle.
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200);

        // Fill rectangle to screen.
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(blueBrush, rect);
    }




    }
  }
```

but it doesnt word, can anyone help me?

Comment: Well where are you trying to *call* `FillRectangleRectangle`? And what exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What happens?

Comment: Try calling the function in the Paint event of your Form.

Answer (score 2):

Add a paint event on your Form and insert the code of your function their (it's correct). 
It should look like this:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200);
   e.Graphics.FillRectangle(blueBrush, rect);
}
```

Whenever you want to redraw your form, use

```
Invalidate();
```

Comment: just this -.- thx                                                      this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(FillRectangleRectangle);

Comment: Do it in the designer - this is what it's for. Usually you don't need to assign the events in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The code that should paint is not being called anywhere. That's what the form's `Paint` event is for. You should assign that event, an then in your code do this:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    FillRectangleRectangle(e);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need refresh the object that you are trying to paint to. Try one of these

```
form.Invalidate();
form.Refresh();
```

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Ah, didn't see that. Sorry.